# What happened to Dr Dre's eye?

Tags: post-apocalyptic, music-video

In the [post-apocalyptic music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWOsbGP5Ox4) for 2Pac's song California Love, Dr Dre's character has an eye patch.

[image]

Is there any canonical source of information, in universe or out of universe, that explains what happened to his eye, or why he wears the patch?

Comment: The one who could answer that should be labeld "Master of Trivia". +1 because this is a tricky question.

Comment: I doubt they come up with any hidden backstory or did any world-building beyond what you see, music videos are mostly just about cool images (in this case meant to echo/parody Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome), unless they're meant as supplements to concept albums (which this wasn't).

Comment: Catastrophic ping pong accident.

Comment: Just to reinforce @Hypnosifl's comment about Mad Max: the video was supposedly filmed in the *original* Thunderdome set.

Comment: "Two gangstas enter, one homie leaves.  Welcome to Thizunderdome biatch!" In all seriousness I don't think this is going to be an answerable question.  Sidenote: is that the same eyepatch Dennis Hopper wore in Waterworld?

Comment: @Monty129 - It's almost identical. I also think it might be an homage to Slick Rick but again, I can't find any canon info.

Comment: The page at http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/California-Love (which seems to have been copied from an earlier version of the wiki article) suggests he was using a football chinstrap as an eyepatch, though there's no citation so it was probably just the judgment of some wiki editor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a work of science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: I believe they just wanted him to look more bad-ass.

Comment: @KyleJones The video seems to be influenced _heavily_ by the _Mad Max_ movies. And while the _song_ doesn't contain any SF content, the _video_ does and is thus a (short) work of SF.

Comment: When I next visit my parents I’ll see if I can dig out the novelisation of the video and check for back-story.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2pac described the video as parody of the film *Mad Max, Beyond Thunderdome* in this set video:

> "Los Angeles - California 2095, after the end of the world, you know, a Mad Max kind of vibe"

That being the case, the clear intention was that 2pac's character is that the eyepatch is simply a steampunk affectation. Note the similarity between 2pac's eyepatch and that worn by Dennis Hopper in another film that was released in the year before; *Waterworld*.

[image: Dennis Hopper wearing an eyepatch in Waterworld]

---

Out of universe, 2pac regularly wore an eyepatch as an homage to his rap mentor [Slick Rick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slick_Rick).

Comment: It is Dr. Dre's character that wears the eyepatch in the video, not 2Pac's.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough (for music video), there is actually a canonical answer, of sorts.  There are two videos for "California Love," and the second one reveals that the first video, with all its *Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome* imagery, was a nightmare Tupac had.  He expresses bewilderment with the dream, none of which really happened.

Comment: Really interesting, I wasn't aware of a second video. Anyway this does not answer the question why Dr. Dre's character in the original one wears the eyepatch.